# How to use Google Blink/Webkit to render HTML code

Tags: c++, dom, webkit, blink

Sorry if the title somewhat ambiguous.
I'm buliding an app that recieve an URL then return the final HTML code (and save it for caching), after Ajax and other js feature executed (something like Phantomjs).
My language can call C++ code, so I think it would be nice if I can buid and use Blink/Webkit libary directly.
The issue is both Blink/Webkit document is too big.

**UPDATE 1**: Which API (Blink has many APIlayer) or a particular class I need to look at?

Do you know any example or tutorial I should look at?
Or any alternative simpler libary?
Thanks

Comment: PhantomJS is stil with QtWebkit(4.8/5), so you have to workaround by writing a simple browser around blink/chromium

Comment: Yes, and I'm asking the way to do that with Blink/Chromium

Comment: please check Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF) https://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/ https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/blogs/an-html5-project-with-chromium-embedded-framework  http://blogs.adobe.com/webplatform/2013/05/01/the-chromium-embedded-framework/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally Chromium project have headless API in development with very good example which can be build using ninja, more information in their project at https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/headless/
A video from BlinkOn https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GivjumRiZ8c&t=838s